# Sierpinsky pyramid L-System

Tags: algorithms, fractals

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) for L-Systems describes many of them, including a couple rules that converge toward the Sierpinsky triangle. That particular fractal also [has a 3D version](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/Sierpinski_pyramid.jpg), which basically uses pyramids instead of triangles. Is there a way to reach this one with an L-system? That same wikipedia page mentions the existence of 3D L-systems, but doesn't explain how they work or give any example as to what their rules would look like.

So first, how do 3D L-systems differ from their 2D counterpart (if there are major différences), and second, can they be used to create this Sierpinsky Pyramids?

I'm trying to create it in Processing, as I managed to draw the 2D version in this software using an L-system before. An example of making a 3D L-system work would be appreciated, but as this is MathOverflow, it is not necessary to include such an example for your answer to be marked as accepted.

Comment: "but as this is math SE, it is not necessary for the answer to be accepted." I don't know what that means, but this is mathoverflow, not math SE.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It seems I've confused the two. I Didn't know there were two math subsites, I just posted in the one that already had Sierpinsky and L system questions. Both site descriptions are similar, what exactly is the difference? between amth SE and MathOverflow?

Comment: MathOverflow is for questions of math research. math.SE is for pretty much any math question. But I still don't know what you mean by "it is not necessary for the answer to be accepted". On both sites it is considered a good thing for a person asking a question to accept an answer, provided of course that there is an answer worthy of being accepted.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm sorry if I worded that badly. I didn't mean that I wouldn't accept the answer. I meant that I would accept an answer even if it didn't include that specific example, because this is not a programming site anyway. I just mentioned the context in case someone happened to be working on the problem for the same reason as I do, then adding a code example would be great. It is simply not necessary to add one for me to actually accept the answer.